# Is the statement "to insert (one object) _over_ (another object)" acceptable usage?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

The common definition for "insert" is:
to put or place in, as in "to insert a key in a lock."

Nonetheless, particularly in technical descriptions, you can find numerous examples where "insert" is used with the preposition "over" to imply a situation where one object is placed or fitted over another object.

e.g., "The catheter is 'inserted over' the guide wire."

The phrase also appears in more common (non-technical) instances.

"Next, an empty beer box is 'inserted over' the bottles and everything is flipped over."
https://www.thefastrack.ca/main/presspack/bar

Since the word "in" is embedded in the definition of "insert," these usages seem contradictory with the definition of "insert." In fact, the beer box is not being inserted over the bottles, but the bottles are being inserted into the box. Similarly, the catheter is not being inserted over the guide wire, but the guide wire is being inserted into the catheter.

On the other hand, in these examples, the "guide wire" and the "bottles" are static or passive objects. Stated otherwise, the objects that are being moved and perform the actions are the "catheter" and the "box." Thus, the phrase "insert over" seems appropriate in this sense.

I could not find any English usage guide that confirms that "insert over" is either acceptable or non-acceptable.

Does anyone know and can you point me to a source?

Comment: I think the real question is: does English have a better alternative? If not, then *"insert over"* should be used here whether or not it is considered correct by the "authorities".

Answer (score 1):

**"Inserted over"** shows up in many editions of this old grammar book:

> [An Abridgement of Murray's English Grammar and Exercises: With
>   Improvements ...enter link description here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=cJgSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA187&dq=%22inserted%20over%20the%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OyUUVZ32FcauogSK3oLgAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22inserted%20over%20the%22%20grammar&f=false), By Lindley Murray,
>   Joab Goldsmith Cooper.
>
> A caret, marked thus a is placed where some
>   word or words are omitted, and which are **inserted over the** line,
>   as

as well as this more recent grammar, the latter for the language of the Hausa:

> [Hausa Grammar: With Exercises, Readings and Vocabulary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Re764L4BPysC&pg=PA68&dq=%22inserted%20over%20the%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JiQUVaG4DcGzogSBsoGQBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22inserted%20over%20the%22%20grammar&f=false)  By
>   Charles Henry Robinson - 2011.
>
> 9) is comparatively seldom **inserted over
>   the** letters

thus I'd take it as relatively OK. Now, the usage might become at times strange, but ....

Comment: That makes sense, @Marius Hancu.  The carat is INserted IN the text, but its vertical position is OVER the letter.

Comment: Yes.  But both of your references are irrelevant to the OP's examples. In his examples, the object x supposedly being "inserted over" y actually **surrounds** y!

Answer (score 0):

In my view "to insert sth over sth" is a bit curious as the Latin verb in-ser-ere (from series row) means to put sth in a row. But if the usage to insert over has become common in certain areas one can't help it. But I think English has a lot of better alternatives for to insert over.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be some insertion going on.

In your first example, the catheter might be being inserted into the patient. If so then it's correct (albeit a bit misleading). If not then it's wrong.

In Marius Hancu's examples the mark is being inserted into the text/page.

In your second example the bottles are inserted into the box not the other way round. I think it is used wrongly there.

If there's no insertion taking place then it is illogical to use the word. I trust I don't need to give the definition of insert.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that this usage is not accurate. For the catheter, I would say it is **slipped over** the guide wire.  In the case of the beer box, I would say it is **positioned over** the bottles and then **lowered** so as to encase them.

Comment: When a surgeon is operating you should never use the word "slipped"!  There's nothing wrong with "the catheter is inserted over the guide wire".

Comment: Does one similarly "insert" a condom?

Comment: If you had the kidney problems I do you would be quite familiar with why a catheter is inserted over a guide wire.  It makes perfect sense.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear of your problem.  In light of that, I'm thinking it would have been more sensitive of me to use a smoother-sounding word than _slip_.  Perhaps  **slide** (or **glide**, depending how you feel about the alliteration of "glide. . . guide...".

Comment: The surgeon first inserts a guide wire into your urethra, through the bladder, and down the selected ureter, using X-rays to know where the wire is headed.  Then he then places the front end of the catheter (a small hose, basically) over the guide wire and inserts that catheter into your urethra, et al.  You can try to dress it up, but "inserts" is precise, concise, and correct.